# Error in Magento installation

Tags: php, magento

[image: This is the snapshot of the problem that i am facing.]

Any solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this link http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/fix-php-settings-check-error-in-magento-2-0-installation-on-localhost/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this link for Fix PHP Settings Check error in Magento 2.0

http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/fix-php-settings-check-error-in-magento-2-0-installation-on-localhost/

Comment: did that . . .happy now?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by the installer, you have to configure your php.ini file.
locate your php.ini with the `php --ini` terminal command. Open the file and locate the `always_populate_raw_post_data` variable. Set it to `-1`

Comment: could you show me a short tutorial? i mean some screenshots etc?

Comment: which os do you use?

Comment: its windows 10. But thanks to @Arun, he pasted the link. that worked.

Comment: And Thank You @Papipone!